# How to set transaction isolation level using ActiveRecord connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions, isolation-level

I need to manage transaction isolation level on a per-transaction basis in a way **portable** across databases (SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL at least).

I know I can do it manually, like that:

```ruby
User.connection.execute('SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE')
```

...but I would expect something like:

```ruby
User.isolation_level( :serializable ) do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This functionality is supported by ActiveRecord itself:

```
MyRecord.transaction(isolation: :read_committed) do
  # do your transaction work
end
```

It supports the ANSI SQL isolation levels:

- `:read_uncommitted`
- `:read_committed`
- `:repeatable_read`
- `:serializable`

This method is available [since Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/392eeecc11a291e406db927a18b75f41b2658253), it was unavailable when the OP asked the question. But for any decently modern Rails application this should be the way to go.

Answer (score 12):

There was no gem available so I developed one (MIT): https://github.com/qertoip/transaction_isolation

Answer (score 12):

Looks Rails4 would have the feature out of box:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/392eeecc11a291e406db927a18b75f41b2658253